# Inner product of tensors: notation conventions

Tags: tensor-calculus

This may be a silly question, but I would just like to confirm something about the inner product of two tensors in Cartesian index notation:

If the inner product of

$A:B = A_{ij}B_{ij}$

in index notation, does the same apply when you do the inner product of a tensor with itself?

So for $A:A$, is the product in index notation written as

$A_{ij}A_{ij}$

or can you not have repeated free indices like that?

Would it instead be written as

$A_{ij}A_{ji}$ or $A_{ij}A_{jk}$ ?

..? I'd just like clarification!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three of those are valid tensor expressions that mean different things.  If you think of $A$ as being like a matrix with $i$ and $j$ being the row and column indices, then $A_{ij}A_{ij}$ is the scalar quantity $\text{Trace}(A A^T)$. $A_{ij}A_{ji}$ is the scalar quantity $\text{Trace}(A^2)$.  And $A_{ij}A_{jk}$ is the matrix (i.e. rank-two tensor) $A^2$ with no trace taken.  Under your definition of inner product, the first one is the correct expression for the inner product of $A$ with itself.